# How I can change object by Id in nested array with childrens, and update state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i toggle isExpanded property on onClick by Id.  I'm using React for this project.
Here is my json data structure.

```
const handleExpandOutlineItem = (id: string) => {}
```

here is my json data structure.

```
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Introduction to Programming',
    isExpanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: '1.1',
        title: 'What is programming?',
        isExpanded: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: '1.1.1',
            title: 'What is programming?',
            isExpanded: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: '1.1.2',
            title: 'What is programming?',
            isExpanded: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '1.2',
        title: 'Programming languages',
        isExpanded: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: '1.2.1',
            title: 'Programming languages',
            isExpanded: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: '1.2.2',
            title: 'Programming languages',
            isExpanded: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I tried to use recursion, but I should also update state

Answer (score 1):

This is a function which updates item in a tree using an `id` in an *immutable way*, which means you can simply pass the *data from state* to it, and store again in state *whatever it returns*.

```
  let data = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Introduction to Programming',
      isExpanded: true,
      children: [
        {
          id: '1.1',
          title: 'What is programming?',
          isExpanded: false,
          children: [
            {
              id: '1.1.1',
              title: 'What is programming?',
              isExpanded: false,
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: '1.1.2',
              title: 'What is programming?',
              isExpanded: false,
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  let flipIsExpanded = (id, tree) => {
    return tree.map((x) => {
      if (x.id === id) {
        return { ...x, isExpanded: !x.isExpanded };
      }

      if (x.children && x.children.length) {
        return { ...x, children: flipIsExpanded(id, x.children) };
      }

      return x;
    });
  };

  console.log(flipIsExpanded('1.1', data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new variable named `newState` with mutated old state

```
const newState = change(oldState);
```

And then set state with `newState`

```
setState(newState)
```